# What acts as the internal storage of an android device?

Tags: internal-storage, hardware

Just like HDD/SSD act as the internal storage for a PC, what exactly acts as the internal storage for an android device?

Comment: It's eMMC or UFS flash memory, embedded with SoC.

Answer (score 3):

It's a flash memory chip on the mainboard of the phone. Usually it has the same electronic interface as an MMC, just soldered onto the board instead of in a socket.

Answer (score 1):

An android's or any other mobile or tablet has storage chip that's embedded on to its motherboard.

To better explain that a typical HDD or Hard disk stores the data on a magnetic tape (slow). RAM will have multiple storage chips where the data will be stored on a circuit so that the data can been accessed quickly. SSD is an upgraded version of RAM with increased storage size (fast) . A mobile device has a chip on its motherboard to store data the same as the chips on a RAM or an SSD.

Answer (score 1):

It's using flash chips, similar to those you have in USB drives. Almost exactly the same.

The storage technology is called [EMMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMMC#eMMC). Linked wikipedia article has some pictures too.

[This](https://www.pine64.org/?product=64gb-emmc) is an example of a 64GB eMMC flash storage module, basically the exact same thing that is used in android phones/tablets too.

[image: Samsung galaxy tab eMMC chip]